# Websphere x JSR 286 best practices

Tags: java, websphere, portlet, jsr286

I am now defining the architectural approach we'll use on a new project with Websphere 6 + JSR86 portlets under a very known portal tool.

What I am planning is to use one .ear file per portlet group (eg.: if two portlets are closely related they'll be on the same .ear) and using shared libraries to hold common code and libraries used by these portlets.

Did someone use this approach (or another one) before? Do you consider this a good approach?

I am looking for some opinions or talking about this architecture with someone (as I didn't find on IBM website a "best practices" article that adresses my scenario), as it looks very clear to me but it wouldn't be good to discover some problem ahead just because I've never asked someone.

Comment: As now I have a long experience with this topic, it's worth to add a comment about what we did along those years and that worked very well.

The related portlets were built as wars grouped inside the same ear, and common libs between those portlets were deployed in the ear level.

Even though we had three big ears (grouped by functionality type) and there were some common libs between them, the better approach was to duplicate those libs and maintain our packages and build process decoupled from environmental (shared libs) elements.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I deployed the portlet to WebSphere Portal in war files, this is the only option if I have access to administration page in Portal view. You have to distinguish admin page of WAS (here you can deploy J2EE apps,but they are not considered as portlet) and admin page of Portal. I put shared libraries in shared folder of portal, but maybe it's not a best practice.